# How to create a self-deleting script?

Tags: php

Is there a possibility to run a php script, that would delete the file, containing this script? If so, how can I do it - or maybe where to look for such way?

*OS: any *nix OS.

EDIT: I mean, that this sshouldn't be exactly php, it an be a bash command, executed via exec() or something else.

Comment: AFAIK, it can't be done

Comment: No, it can't be done because the file is in use

Comment: asprin: not sure why you minused the question, but nevertheless: I've found out that exec('rm __FILE__') or unlink it works fine, if ran from the command line.

Comment: I seldom downvote and FYI I didn't in this case

Comment: asprin: sorry for that. Just the coincidence and being not familiar with "common unspeakable rules" of resource. Disregards please previous my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `unlink(__FILE__);`  to unlink the file and delte.  but iam not sure this will help when file in use.

Comment: If ran from the command line it does work for me. However not the variant for Apache. But as I wanted to know a theoretical possibility, then this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you may easily remove the file using `unlink()` and before closing file, you have to use `fclose()` for closing the current executing file

Answer (score 0):

Both of this work fine .. form command line and from http request.
For HTTP request the web-data user need to have proper permission over the file/directory.

`<? unlink(__FILE__); ?>`

**on server linux**
`<?php exec('rm thisfile.php') ?>`

Answer (score -1):

No you can't.

Because apache using this php file on runtime.

It's not a direct answer but if @Abhik Chakraborty is right, you can put a *deleteeverything.php* file and this file can delete other PHP files :)

Comment: Nope, he sin't. It's not even the real case.
Additionally, I've never said it should be used by Apache, running from comand line is ok.
See comment below - thanks to Sagar Panchal.

Comment: It was done exactly after your answer as I found out that I wasn't clear enough. Thank you nevertheless. :)

Comment: Just tested the scenario and it is works (it is not logical but this is PHP !)